# Adjust Rmarkdown's inline chunk output - increase no. of columns displayed?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

This is a workflow related question. I'm trying out working only (or mostly) in the Rmarkdown source window with the options set to "Chunk output inline". So with R open, there is just one big window -The environment, Console and File windows being minimized.

**My question**: Is there some option to change the number of **columns** displayed? I want to increase the numbers of columns visible without scrolling (see screenshot below), and since there is enough space I think it should be possible to display more of them.

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: There is an option. Just add `cols.print = 12` (or whatever number you want) to global options.

Also, people might find this 'manual' on markdown useful: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#paged-printing

Comment: How is this done? I tried running {r setup, include=FALSE, cols.print = 10} in the first chunk header and knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) as the body of the first chunk, but I'm still only getting five columns in in-line output,

Comment: maybe your screen is not wide enough? I can't remember exactly what I did, but I guess I should recommend using quarto that will replace rmarkdown. It's very similar...